Dealing with columns with datatype object
I read in a stored numpy array with dtype object in polars.
I want to change column dtype from object to float in the polars dataframe.
Minimal example:
# generate sample data
data = {"1": ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0"],
        "2": [10, 20, 30, 40]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema={'1':pl.Object, '2':pl.Object})

# what I want to do
df.with_columns(pl.col('2').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False))

The last line yields an error:

polars.exceptions.ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type

How can I do this?

Usually, by the time an object dtype made it into your dataframe, it is already too late to perform any native polars operation on it. Still, you can apply pl.Expr.map_elements to map a user-defined function over elements.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("1").map_elements(lambda x: x, return_dtype=pl.String),
    pl.col("2").map_elements(lambda x: x, return_dtype=pl.Int32),
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 10  │
│ 2.0 ┆ 20  │
│ 3.0 ┆ 30  │
│ 4.0 ┆ 40  │
└─────┴─────┘


thanks this is exactly what i needed!
However, I had to assign it again, so df = df.with_columns( ...

@tamtam_ Glad it helped! You are right. As most polars DataFrame methods, pl.DataFrame.with_columns is not in-place.
